# Multiple columns in same and Different table combined into one single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I am trying to combine multiple columns into single row by using the code below.

```
select A.CreateDate as JoinDate, B.Section, C.UserName, cast(B.TotalProgress as decimal(10,0)) as TotalProgress
from B
join C on B.UserName = C.UserName 
join A on C.UserId = A.UserId
WHERE (A.[CreateDate] >= '1/1/2018') 
AND ((A.[CreateDate]) <= ('1/1/2019'))
UNION
select A.CreateDate as JoinDate, B.Section, C.UserName, cast(D.TotalProgress as decimal(10,0)) as TotalProgress
from B 
join C on B.UserName = C.UserName 
join A on C.UserId = A.UserId 
join D on C.UserName = D.UserName 
WHERE (A.[CreateDate] >= '1/1/2018') 
AND ((A.[CreateDate]) <= ('1/1/2019'))
UNION
select A.CreateDate as JoinDate, B.Section, C.UserName, cast(B.TotalProgress_A as decimal(10,0)) as TotalProgress
from B 
join C on B.UserName = C.UserName 
join A on C.UserId = A.UserId
WHERE (A.[CreateDate] >= '1/1/2018') 
AND ((A.[CreateDate]) <= ('1/1/2019'))
order by A.CreateDate desc
```

The problem is that the query is making duplicates. I think that the problem is the TotalProgress in the select statement. Is there any way I can eliminate the duplicates in the query? I'm using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio to run this query.

Below are the results of the query when I run it.

```
JoinDate    | Section | UserName | TotalProgress
2019-01-03  | 1A      | test1    | 0
2019-01-03  | 1A      | test1    | 1
2019-01-03  | 1A      | test1    | 22
2019-01-03  | 2B      | test2    | 0
2019-01-03  | 2B      | test2    | 33
2019-01-03  | 3C      | test3    | 0
2019-01-03  | 3C      | test3    | 1
```

As you can see. You will notice that the progress is the only different. I have tried to use distinct but its not working. There are some instances that some rows in total progress are all 0. But in general , I want it to be like this.

```
JoinDate    | Section | UserName | TotalProgress
2019-01-03  | 1A      | test1    | 22
2019-01-03  | 2B      | test2    | 33
2019-01-03  | 3C      | test3    | 1
```

Comment: You really need to add sample data to this question which explains what the perceived problem is, and what you think needs to be fixed.  Also, define what you mean by "duplicate."  Strictly speaking, there _can't_ be any duplicates in the result set from the above query, because SQL Server would filter off all duplicate records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using `union` for this logic.  I think you want something like this:

```
select A.CreateDate as JoinDate, B.Section, C.UserName,
       bd.TotalProgress
from B join
     C
     on B.UserName = C.UserName join
     A
     on C.UserId = A.UserId left join
     D 
     on C.UserName = D.UserName outer apply
     (select max(TotalProgress) as TotalProgress
      from (values (B.TotalProgress ), (B.TotalProgress_A), (D.TotalProgress )
           ) v(TotalProgress)
     ) bd
where A.[CreateDate] >= '2018-01-01' and
      A.[CreateDate]) < '2019-01-01'  -- guessing you don't really want any data from 2019
```

The purpose of the `outer apply` is just to get the maximum value of the three columns.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out and for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking Union 3 times and hence the similar records with different TotalProgress  are coming. Seems normal.
What do you want - to put all the 3 rows as 3 columns in a single row?

Comment: There is a 2nd table below. I want it to be like that.